# What is the correct disassembly for ARM7 opcode E1F120D1?

Tags: disassembly, arm

I'm writing a disassembler for ARM opcodes and I'm struggling with a particular encoding. The offending instruction is `E1F120D1`. I think I've followed the instructions closely, and expect the disassemble to be `mvns r2,r1` but trying it on http://www.onlinedisassembler.com gives me `ldsrb r2,[r1,#1]!`.

It seems like the low-order `20D1` in the instruction is causing online disassembler ti switch from `mvn` to `ldrsb`. Is this a bug in the disassembler -- not likely -- or my misunderstanding the instruction encodings in the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the ARM Architecture Reference Manual, you should be able to see that Chapter A5 takes you through the decoding of ARM instructions.

Starting with table A5-1, your instruction has -

```
cond (31-28) = 1110
op1 (27-25) =  000
```

This matches

```
cond = not 1111, op1 = 00x  => Data Processing & Miscellaneous instructions (A5.2)
```

Then for table A5-2 in section A5.2, your instruction has -

```
op (25) = 0
op1 (24-20) = 11111
op2 (7-4) = 1101
```

The encoding that matches these bits is -

```
op = 0, op1 = not 0xx1x, op2 = 11x1 => Extra load/store instructions (A5.2.8)
```

Finally for table A5-10 in section A5.2.8, your instruction has -

```
op2 (6-5) = 10
op1 (24-20) = 11111
Rn (19-16) = 0001
```

This matches

```
op2 = 10, op1 = xx1x1, Rn = not 1111 => LDRSB (immediate)
```

So, yes, bits 7-4 definitely affect the decoding of this instruction.

Comment: Indeed this correct. My mistake was using a very old reference for the ARM architecture, where the LDRSB instruction was not implemented yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is LDRSB:

Cond 000 PU0W L Rn Rd 0 0 0 0 Rm

This is MVN:

Cond 001 1111 ...

The difference is in the I register.  MVN is register to register only.